# BackgroundDownloadAsync not downloading?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to use LiveConnectClient.BackgroundDownloadAsync to copy a file from Skydrive onto my computer. My code is below (this is a C# Metro app running on Win8).

```
var copy = connect.BackgroundDownloadAsync(f.id, dest);
LiveDownloadOperationResult result = await copy;
```

The result I get back contains no error, yet when I go have a look I see only the first 1K of my file. So my questions are:

- Has someone used BackgroundDownloadAsync successfully?
- Can someone suggest something I might have missed, that would match the symptoms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to add "/content" to the ID of the file you want to download. Otherwise, you get the metadata.